# How to get an element from UDF function if it returns tuple? (PySpark)

Tags: pyspark

So I have an UDF function that returns tuple of 2 elements.

Let's say it's called `foo()`.

And here's what I wanna do:

```
some_df = another_df.withColumn('Column', <If, else and so on>, foo(*args)[0])
```

How exactly can I do this? I described schema for that udf function as

```
coord_schema = StructType([
    StructField("1st arg", StringType(), False),
    StructField("2nd arg", StringType(), False)
])
```

But when I execute it doesn't work and show a lot of errors.

Thank you beforehand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return tuples from an udf by using Sparks `ArrayType`. Here is a small example demonstrating this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,)], ["TestValue"])

@udf(returnType=T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))
def sample_udf(s):
  return (str(s), str(s+s))
          
df = df.withColumn("strings", sample_udf(F.col("TestValue")))
df = df.withColumn("string1", sample_udf(F.col("TestValue"))[0])
df = df.withColumn("string2", sample_udf(F.col("TestValue"))[1])
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
|TestValue|strings|string1|string2|
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
|        1| [1, 2]|      1|      2|
|        2| [2, 4]|      2|      4|
|        3| [3, 6]|      3|      6|
|        4| [4, 8]|      4|      8|
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
```